# TrulyObservableCollection not notifying when changing value on UI

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm using [TrulyObservableCollection](https://gist.github.com/itajaja/7507120) to observe a collection changed event.

Now I want when UI changed the value, the collection can also be notified, and get all the new values.

So how to do when I modify the textbox's value, the collection can be also notified.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Width="20" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

TrulyObservableCollection<ViewItemModel> viewItemModels = new TrulyObservableCollection<ViewItemModel>();

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            viewItemModels.CollectionChanged += ViewItemModels_CollectionChanged;
            viewItemModels.ItemChanged += ViewItemModels_ItemChanged;

            ViewItemModel viewItemModel1 = new ViewItemModel { Name = "1", Value = 1 };
            ViewItemModel viewItemModel2 = new ViewItemModel { Name = "2", Value = "2" };
            ViewItemModel viewItemModel3 = new ViewItemModel { Name = "3", Value = true };

            viewItemModels.Add(viewItemModel1);
            viewItemModels.Add(viewItemModel2);
            viewItemModels.Add(viewItemModel3);


            DataContext = viewItemModels;
        }

        private void ViewItemModels_ItemChanged(object sender, ItemChangedEventArgs<ViewItemModel> e)
        {
            
        }

        private void ViewItemModels_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
```

Comment: When an item in the collection changes its internal state, **the collection itself does not change**, so why would you want to notify a collection changed? It is redundant. The items in the `ItemsControl` will be recreated, leaving the same items as before. In essence, your question is how to fire the `CollectionChanged` event if a property value of any item changes? What is the real problem that you want to solve?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple samples of this kind of collection.

This is one that I have used successfully. It adds a new Event ItemPropertyChanged.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyNamespace
{
  public class FullyObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
        where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when a property is changed within an item.
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> ItemPropertyChanged;

        public FullyObservableCollection() : base()
        { }

        public FullyObservableCollection(List<T> list) : base(list)
        {
            ObserveAll();
        }

        public FullyObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) : base(enumerable)
        {
            ObserveAll();
        }

        protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove ||
                e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
            {
                foreach (T item in e.OldItems)
                    item.PropertyChanged -= ChildPropertyChanged;
            }

            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add ||
                e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
            {
                foreach (T item in e.NewItems)
                    item.PropertyChanged += ChildPropertyChanged;
            }

            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void ClearItems()
        {
            foreach (T item in Items)
                item.PropertyChanged -= ChildPropertyChanged;

            base.ClearItems();
        }

        private void ObserveAll()
        {
            foreach (T item in Items)
                item.PropertyChanged += ChildPropertyChanged;
        }

        private void ChildPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ItemPropertyChanged?.Invoke ( sender, e ) ;
        }
    }

}
```